# Select answers that matches the correct answers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing online exam website and i have a trouble writing query to check if the provided answer is correct or not in MCQ questions. The question might contains more then 1 correct answer and if only one correct answer is wrong, question answer is wrong

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` longblob,
  `type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 - MCQ / 1 - T/F /2- COMPLETE/',
  `instructorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TF` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` longblob,
  `isRight` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `testID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `settingID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instructorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `result_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resultID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TF` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `answers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `answers_ibfk_1` (`questionID`);

ALTER TABLE `question`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `question_ibfk_1` (`instructorID`),
  ADD KEY `question_ibfk_2` (`courseID`);

ALTER TABLE `result`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `testID` (`testID`),
  ADD KEY `studentID` (`studentID`),
  ADD KEY `instructorID` (`instructorID`),
  ADD KEY `settingID` (`settingID`);

ALTER TABLE `result_answers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `questionID` (`questionID`),
  ADD KEY `answerID` (`answerID`),
  ADD KEY `result_answers_ibfk_1` (`resultID`);

ALTER TABLE `answers`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=516;

ALTER TABLE `question`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=20;

ALTER TABLE `result`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

ALTER TABLE `result_answers`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;

ALTER TABLE `answers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`questionID`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE `question`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`instructorID`) REFERENCES `instructor` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `result`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`testID`) REFERENCES `test` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`studentID`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`instructorID`) REFERENCES `instructor` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `settings` FOREIGN KEY (`settingID`) REFERENCES `settings_profiles` (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `result_answers`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_answers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`resultID`) REFERENCES `result` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_answers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`questionID`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `result_answers_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`answerID`) REFERENCES `answers` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

[complete database sql](http://mt2arab.altervista.org/onlineq%20(3).sql) 
i made some search and found out that it's a problem called relational division so i tried to create a function to return true if question in a result is solved correctly

```
BEGIN

   DECLARE RES Boolean;

   IF (SELECT resultID
            From result_answers
            WHERE answerID IN (SELECT id FROM answers where isRight = 1 and questionID = qID) AND resultID = resID
            GROUP BY resultID
            HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers where isRight = 1 and questionID = qID)) THEN
      SET RES = True;
   ELSE
      SET RES = False;

   END IF;

   RETURN RES;

END
```

it returns true if one correct answer is provided even of the other answer is wrong

i need this query to return true if and only if the student answers matches all correct answers of a specific question in a specific result

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question would be a big help.

Comment: We can't use images of your sample data to create tables for testing. Please post a [mcve] in the form of text (CREATE TABLE, INSERT, etc.), along with the sample output you'd like to obbtain from that sample data.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Sorry to effectively be guessing here but I plugged a couple valid numbers into ```SELECT *
            From result_answers, answers
            WHERE result_answers.answerID = answers.id 
            AND answerID IN (SELECT id FROM answers where questionID = 7) AND resultID = 3
            GROUP BY resultID
            HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers where isRight = 1 and questionID = 7 AND resultID = 3)``` and wondered if that worked for you

Comment: @NathanHawks thank you, but the query still returning rows when only one correct answer is provided

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have three cases:

1. A correct answer was chosen
2. An incorrect answer was chosen
3. A correct answer was NOT chosen (this means an outer join is needed).

The query below gathers this info:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(case when isRight = 1 and resultID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as rightAnswers, 
   SUM(case when isRight = 0 and resultID is not null then 1 else 0 end) as wrongAnswers,
   SUM(case when isRight = 1 and resultID is null then 1 else 0 end) as missedAnswers
FROM
   answers a left join 
   (select * from result_answers where resultID = 3) ra on a.questionID = ra.questionID AND a.ID = ra.answerID
WHERE a.questionID = 2
```

If rightAnswers > 0 and wrongAnswer = 0 and misssedAnswers= 0 the question has been answered correctly.  These cases could be combined into a single variable if you prefer.  HTH.